# How do I combine these similar linq queries into one?

Tags: c#, linq

This is probably a basic LINQ question. I have need to select one object and if it is null select another. I'm using linq to objects in the following way, that I know can be done quicker, better, cleaner...

```
    public Attrib DetermineAttribution(Data data)
    {

        var one = from c in data.actions
                           where c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeOne
                           select new Attrib 
                                      {
                                          id = c.id,
                                          name = c.name
                                      };
        if( one.Count() > 0)
            return one.First();

        var two = from c in data.actions
                  where c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeTwo
                  select new Attrib
                             {
                                 id = c.id,
                                 name = c.name
                             };
        if (two.Count() > 0 )
            return two.First();

  }
```

The two linq operations differ only on the where clause and I know there is a way to combine them. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use .Any() instead of .Count(). Count() goes through the entire sequence, whereas Any just checks the first item for existance.

Comment: @MikeD: It should be noted that the above doesn't compile, as you don't return a value in the case that both sequences do not have an item you are looking for.

Comment: sorry, I was trying to clean up my method into something concise in the SO window and apparently tooke out too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this solution is simple and efficient:

```
public Attrib DetermineAttribution(Data data)
{
    var c = data.actions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeOne) ??
            data.actions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeTwo);
    return c != null ? new Attrib { id = c.id, name = c.name } : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use the query syntax, but it preserves the logic that an element of type `ActionTypeOne` is return before an element of `ActionTypeTwo`.  And because of lazy evaluation, the second query won't be executed unless there are no elements of type `ActionTypeOne`.

```
public Attrib DetermineAttribution(Data data)
{

    return data.actions.Where( c => c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeOne)
              .Concat( data.actions.Where( c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeTwo ) )
              .Select( c => new Attrib
                         {
                             id = c.id,
                             name = c.name
                         })
              .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var one = (from c in data.actions
                           where (c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeOne) || (c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeTwo)
                           select new Attrib 
                                      {
                                          id = c.id,
                                          name = c.name
                                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This does not guarantee that ActionTypeOne will be found before ActionTypeTwo though. It finds the first record that is ActionTypeOne *or* ActionTypeTwo.

Comment: You could use orderby to ensure the order in which items are retrieved.

Comment: @codymanix: You'd have to specify a custom comparer so that elements of type `ActionTypeOne` are returned before elements of type `ActionTypeTwo` (there's no guarantee they will be sorted that way by default).  It would also take something that can run in linear time and turn it into an n log(n).  Doesn't matter 99% of the time, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
 public Attrib DetermineAttribution(Data data)
 {
        var types = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Action)).Cast<Action>();
        var merged = from c in data.actions
                     from t in types
                     where c.actionType == t
                     select new Attrib {id = c.id, name = c.name};

        return merged.FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var one =  from c in data.actions
                where c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeOne
                    || c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeTwo
                orderby c.actionType == Action.ActionTypeOne ? 0 : 1
                select new Attrib 
                                {
                                  id = c.id,
                                  name = c.name
                                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

The equivalent SQL query would be ( I used a Case statement because I did not know the data type of the ActionType column):

```
Select TOP 1 id, name
From Actions
where ActionType In(ActionTypeOne, ActionTypeTwo)
Order By Case ActionType When 1 Then 0 Else 1 End ASC
```